# I need advice on partition sizing/placement, please

Tags: dual-boot, partitioning

I have installed 14.04 lts in a dual boot configuration with Windows 7. HD size is 500 GB. Before installing Ubuntu I used gparted to get approximately a 250 GB partition for the Ubuntu installation.

What I would like to do now is give the root partition 30GB, increase the size of the swap partition, and have the rest available for other things. Given my current configuration, can I just do the resizing without moving anything around? I'm confused by the 233GB extended partion at sda4.

This is how things are set up at present:

```
Device Boot      Start         End      Blocks   Id  System
/dev/sda1            2048    34605055    17301504   27  Hidden NTFS WinRE
/dev/sda2   *    34605056    34809855      102400    7  HPFS/NTFS/exFAT
/dev/sda3        34809856   488038323   226614234    7  HPFS/NTFS/exFAT
/dev/sda4       488038398   976771071   244366337    5  Extended
Partition 4 does not start on physical sector boundary.
/dev/sda5       488038400   964521983   238241792   83  Linux
/dev/sda6       964524032   976771071     6123520   82  Linux swap / Solaris
```

Comment: To clarify, you want to shrink `sda5` (your linux partition), expand your swap, and create another partition for everything else you might want to store?

Comment: Yes, thank you, that is what I would like to achieve. I would also like to be able to readily access that created partition from Ubuntu. Specifically, I would like to put /home and /usr there.

Comment: Yes, it would be possible. PLease post your gparted screenshot to imgur.com and again post the uploaded link here.

Comment: http://i.imgur.com/00aC40c.png

Comment: So, has anyone any advice?